# What are the restrictions for the CPU when it is in user mode?

Tags: cpu

I know that when the CPU is in user mode, it can't access all memory, it also can't execute some CPU instructions (called "privileged instructions" I believe).

But are these two restrictions the only things that the CPU cannot do when it is in user mode? For example, what about accessing the CPU registers, can the CPU access all of the CPU registers when it is in user mode?

Comment: Is there a particular CPU or architecture you are interested in?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, x86 and x86_64.

Comment: The Intel CPUs don't have a "user mode".  They have several modes of operation.  The common separation between user code and operating system code is handled using "privilege levels" and other restrictions controlled thru the segment registers and paging tables.  Device drivers can reside somewhere in between.  Consult the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm What do you mean there is no user mode in  Intel CPUs, do you mean it is not formally called "user mode"? because based on what I have read, an x86 CPU for example have 4 protection rings, ring 0 is the most privileged (which we can call kernel mode), and ring 3 is the least privileged (which we can call user mode).

Comment: There's nothing called "user mode" in the documentation.  Applications would run at Protection Level 3.  The CPU isn't in this mode.  The protection level is part of the thread properties (CS and SS registers).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But why all of the tutorials that I have read online say that the CPU can be either in user mode or in kernel mode and that the CPU have 4 protections rings, for example this tutorial (https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode/) says: *"x86 CPU hardware actually provides four protection rings: 0, 1, 2, and 3. Only rings 0 (Kernel) and 3 (User) are typically used."*

Comment: Saying that the CPU is in user mode is a simplification.  The CPU is in Protected Mode.  The common set of restrictions applied to applications (including running at at Protection Level 3) is called "user mode", but that can vary from OS to OS, and can be controlled on a per thread basis.  It is up to the OS to define how restricted these least privileged programs are.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I did some research, and I think that I understood what you mean, which is the following: It is true that when when the CPU is in "kernel mode" (I know it is not officially called that) it can do everything (access all memory, execute any CPU instruction, access all registers), but it is not true that when the CPU is in "user mode" (also I know it is not officially called that) that it can only do a fixed limited set of things...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ...What can really happen is that when the CPU is in "kernel mode", it can give a user mode program more privileges, for example it can give some process access to kernel space memory by mapping a portion of the process's page table to those areas of kernel memory, it can also allow a process to access some privileged CPU instructions (like `IN` and `OUT`). Am I correct?

Comment: Mostly.  All memory accesses (even by the OS) need to be mapped into the process space (using the segment registers and page table).  OS (kernel) threads do not have to be running at Privilege Level 0.  While the OS could give a process access to kernel space memory, it probably shouldn't.  Each process would have access to its own memory space.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly some registers that need to be protected from user-mode reading and/or writing.

There are several ways this might be done:

- the registers that need to be protected can only be accessed by special instructions, and, in user-mode these instructions are privileged.
- there are general instructions that can access both general registers and privileged registers, but may access the latter only in supervisor mode.

In either case, if virtualization is desired (guest hosting an OS or VM), then accesses to the privileged registers (both read and write), need to fault to the supervisor (allowing the supervisor to emulate their effect in some way), rather than silently doing nothing like returning zero on read or ignoring writes.